# Синтаксис c#. Безымянная функция передающаяся в метод

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Часто встречаю подобную конструкцию, но не понимаю откуда там берется аргумент с уже присвоенным значением `option`?

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options => //CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Login");
});
```

Comment: Это лямбда. options в данном случае - это не имя функции, а имя первого аргумента функции. Вам понятно почему вы можете использовать аргумент test в теле этой функции? void a(T test) { ... }

Comment: ну если я где то вызову a() то передам ей что-то, а тут где мы что предаем? Как optoins у нас стала ссылаться на что то?

Comment: Примерно так: `public void AddCookie(Action<Options> lambda) { lambda(options); }`. Вы передаете AddCookie свою функцию с заданной сигнатурой (смотрите делегаты в C#) и она вызывает ее передавая параметр.

Comment: >>а тут где мы что предаем?<< тут это значение options передаёт метод AddCookie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте напишем простую реализацию метода ForEach для массива, которая будет принимать *метод* и применять его ко всем элементам массива, это может выглядеть, например, как-то так:

```
public static void ForEach(int[] array, Action<int> action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
        action(array[i]);
}
```

с первым параметром всё понятно - это массив, а вот второй параметр - это *метод, принимающий параметр типа int и не возвращающий значение*,

Т.е. мы можем написать такой метод, соответствующий указанной сигнатуре:

```
static void Method(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Элемент: " + x);
}
```

и передать его вместе с массивом:

```
int[] myarray = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
ForEach(myarray, Method);
```

Если мы захотим вывести квадраты элементов массива, то нам придется создать еще один метод. Вот, для того, чтобы код не разбухал от таких коротких методов, используемых всего один раз, был придуман такой сокращенный синтаксис анонимных методов, при котором метод с нужной нам сигнатурой создается непосредственно перед передачей:

```
ForEach(myarray, (int x) => { Console.WriteLine("Элемент: " + x); });
```

Т.е. здесь, прямо внутри вызова мы написали метод абсолютно аналогичный методу `Method(int x)`. Если компилятор может вывести тип параметра этого метода, то этот тип можно опустить:

```
ForEach(myarray, (x) => { Console.WriteLine("Элемент: " + x); });
```

В тех случаях, когда передаваемый метод имеет *ровно один* параметр, то можно опустить так же скобки вокруг него (если параметров несколько или параметров нет вообще - от скобок не избавиться):

```
ForEach(myarray, x => { Console.WriteLine("Элемент: " + x); });
```

Если тело метода состоит ровно из одного оператора, то можно опустить также фигурные скобки вокруг него:

```
ForEach(myarray, x => Console.WriteLine("Элемент: " + x));
```

Этот код работает абсолютно также, как и первоначальный (с передачей в параметре `Method`), так вот, наш `x` это тот же `x`, что и параметр в методе `Method`, т.е. просто имя параметра, которое мы будем использовать в теле метода. При желании вы можете назвать его по другому, например, `element`, но тогда и в теле метода придется использовать именно это имя: `Console.WriteLine("Элемент: " + element)`

Это сокращенный синтаксис лямбда-выражений, еще раньше, до его введения, мог использоваться синтаксис анонимных делегатов:

```
ForEach(myarray, delegate(int x) { Console.WriteLine("Элемент: " + x); });
```

Это по прежнему код дающий тот же самый результат.

Comment: Большое спасибо.  Но у меня остался вопрос, если мы передаем только метод то с чем он внутри работает? Откуда он берет options?

Comment: Посмотрите код `ForEach`, именно он вызывает внутри переданный ему метод и он, соответственно передает ему параметр.

Comment: Откуда он берет options - это деталь реализации и вам это не важно, может он самостоятельно создает экземпляр или получает откуда-то. Ваша задача рассказать ему как этот options (на самом деле он имеет тип `CookieAuthenticationOptions`) настроить, вот вы ему и говорите "установи этому CookieAuthenticationOptions свойство LoginPath в такое-то значение".

Comment: Вот этот метод, который вы фактически вызываете: [AddCookie(AuthenticationBuilder, String)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.cookieextensions.addcookie?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_CookieExtensions_AddCookie_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationBuilder_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Cookies_CookieAuthenticationOptions__) А [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) сведения о различных настройках

Answer (score 3):

Я не могу поместить маленький пример в комментариях, поэтому оставлю его здесь.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Options
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LoginPath { get; set; }
    }

    public class Authentication
    {
        private Options myOptions = new Options();
        public void AddCookie(Action<Options> lambda)
        {
            // !вызов с передачей параметра!
            lambda(myOptions);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Authentication().AddCookie(options => //CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```